# Why some strings are quoted with double backticks and double single quotes in man pages?

Tags: man

For example, in the `yes` man page:

> yes outputs expletive, or, by default, ``y''

Why is "y" quoted this way?

Comment: Care to tell us what your system is? Most probably it's just a mistake...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be from `yes` from coreutils.

Comment: In print the lefthand quotes are different from righthand quotes. nroff is processing the manpage in an attempt to mimic this. These quotes are not at all related to, or attempt to simulate, shell quotes.

Comment: This is actually in OS X, I assumed it was the same everywhere.

Comment: wurtel is right. It is trying to get [this effect](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F9VoG.png) by using two left-single-quotes and two right-single-quotes, but screen fonts hardly ever look like that any more. P.S. I see the same usage in various Linux man pages, although it seems to be with individual quotes (e.g., `\`y'`) more often than double.