# man/troff: Convert ^ to ˆ

Tags: perl, man, groff

This is a follow-up on [man -t converts - to −](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354895/man-t-converts-to-%E2%88%92)

This time the problem is with ^ which `troff` thinks should be changed into ˆ.

Is there a general way of telling `man -t` not to mess with the input?

If not: How do I fix the ˆ?

MCVE:

```
$ cat foo.pod
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

=head1 A

  ^

=cut

$ pod2man foo.pod | man -tl - | ps2pdf - foo.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Troff turns `^` into a circumflex accent.

The simple solution to your issue, with a not-so-simple implementation, is to arrange that every  `^` in the pod file gets turned into the troff sequence `\(ha`. 
I don't know the internals of `Pod.pm`, so instead of patching that I'll give a filter you can use on the output of `pod2man`, before it gets sent to `man -t`.

Complicating matters is that `pod2man` produces some lines with `^` in them. We can't alter them.

```
pod2man foo.pod | \
perl -pe '/\.[ ]*ds[ ]*\^/ || s/(?<!\\\*)\^/\\(ha/g' | \
man -tl - | ps2pdf - foo.pdf
```

The Perl command does this:

- if the line contains a `.ds ^` directive, don't alter it
- otherwise, every occurrence of `^` is replaced by `\(ha`, but `\*^` isn't touched.